# CSS class selector range

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this bit of CSS below. How can I shorten the list of circle classes? I want to be able to say "FROM .circle01 TO .circle23"

```
 .circle01, .circle02, .circle03, .circle04, .circle05, .circle06, .circle07, .circle08, .circle09, .circle10,
        .circle11, .circle12, .circle13, .circle14, .circle15, .circle16, .circle17, .circle18, .circle19, .circle20,
        .circle21, .circle22, .circle23 {
            background-color: none;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 20000;
            top: 255px; /*30*/ 
            width: 252px;
            left: 145px;
            height: 71px;
            pointer-events:none;
        }
```

In pseudo code, I want something like:

```
.circle01 to .circle23 {
       background-color: none;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 20000;
        top: 255px; /*30*/ 
        width: 252px;
        left: 145px;
        height: 71px;
        pointer-events:none;
}
```

EDIT, found a solution:

```
        div[class^="circle"] {
            background-color: none;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 20000;
            top: 255px; /*30*/ 
            width: 252px;
            left: 145px;
            height: 71px;
            pointer-events:none;
        }
```

Comment: You need a common class for all of them for this work. You can't write loops in CSS

Comment: Just as an aside, if each of those are truly unique, you likely want to be using ID's for them rather than classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this attribute selector

```
[class^=circle]
```

to match all elements whose class attribute begins with `circle`.

Note it will also match `circlebar`, and won't match `shape circle01`.

---

Or this one

```
[class*=circle]
```

to match all elements whose class attribute contains `circle`

Note it will also match `foocirclebar`.

Comment: Adding to this: `div[class|="circle"]` assuming its contained withing a div

Comment: That's the right answer considering a 'css only' solution, but not the most semanticist/faster, right?

Comment: @enapupe Yeah, I don't like numbered classes because I don't find them semantic.

Answer (score 3):

Add class circle to every circle, class="circle circle01", class="circle circle02", etc
than:

```
.circle { 
        background-color: none;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 20000;
        top: 255px; /*30*/ 
        width: 252px;
        left: 145px;
        height: 71px;
        pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a common class to each of them and simply select them like that:

```
.circleCommon {
   background-color: none;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20000;
    top: 255px; /*30*/ 
    width: 252px;
    left: 145px;
    height: 71px;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

You can't use ranges in CSS.

Comment: Thanks. Found a solution.

   div[class^="circle"] {
    stuff;
   }

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to include every circle class name in the CSS. The better way to do it would be with a jQuery each that applies a class to the first x of .circle

Comment: Why????????????????????????????????? People nowadays add jQuery before even declaring doctype..

Comment: Well js or jq. Just said jquery because most people do use it. Selecting a range would only be possible that way, though rethinking how you've coded things is likely the better option.